# MVC validator for custom object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-validation

I have some model for my View and custom object as a property there, like this:

```
class SomeModel {
  public object Data { get; set; }
}
```

and in View:

```
@model Blablabla.SomeModel
```

For example, in Model.Data I put some object with properties: `Name`, `DateBirth` and `Amount`.
I'd like to create editors for these properties, like this:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Data.Name)
@Html.ValidateMessageFor(m => m.Data.Name)
```

But I cannot do this since `m.Data` is `object`, and compiler will not pass this. In case with EditorFor - I can replace it with my own `<input type="..." ... />` without problems.

But I cannot find a way how to include MVC's Validator (from MicrosoftMvcValidation.js) to my input, and I don't want to create my own javascripts for all attributes from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`.

Is there a way to use **MVC's Validator** for my custom object without information about what properties it has (I'm generating editors by enumerating properties through the Reflection).

**UPD:** I cannot write just `@Html.ValidateMessageFor(m => m.Data.Name)` because I don't know about the property name before. I can do it only through the Reflection like this: `@Html.ValidateMessageFor(m => m.Data.GetType().GetProperty(colName).GetValue(m.Data, null))`, where `colName` contains the property name (Name, DateBirth or Amount).

Answer (score 0):

I'm always hesitant to suggest use of the `dynamic` keyword however for what you're doing, this is at least one option.

By making your `Data` property of type `dynamic` you'll be able to set properties on it at runtime and also use it in your `EditorFor`.

```
public dynamic Data { get; set; }
```

Comment: Ok, this is my fault that I not mentioned it above -- I cannot write just `m.Data.Name`, but can do something like: `@Model.Data.GetValue(colName)` in parent loop through the Reflection. Updated the question.